# How to filter between dates? R+MySQL

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a [dashboard](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/087-crandash/) linked with an SQL database with [renderValueBox](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/087-crandash/server.R) function, but I'm not able to filter between dates.

---

```r
library(RMariaDB)
storiesDb <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='user', password=localuserpassword, dbname='dbname', host='localhost')
        querysel1=paste("SELECT COLNAME1
                 FROM   TABLENAME
                 where DATECOLMN
                 between '",Sys.Date(),"'and '",Sys.Date()-1 ,"'   ;           ",sep= ''
        )
        #querysel1=gsub("'"," ",querysel1)
        rs = dbSendQuery(storiesDb,querysel1)
        
        dbFetch(rs)
```

---

The result is returning me 0 lines, even though there are lines compatible with the condition described in between... Is there an error in the way I sent the query?

Comment: first, query between `Sys.date()-1 and Sys.date()` (you made the contrary)

Comment: then, make sure that `as.character(Sys.date())` corresponds to the format expected by MySQL

Comment: ooh man how could I not understand that ??? the error was just the location of the -1

Comment: Don't you want to turn your comment into an answer? you solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BETWEEN` expects dates in ascending order.

Try

```
between Sys.date()-1 and Sys.date()
```

instead of

```
between Sys.date() and Sys.date()-1
```